# Error generated during execution of a triggers

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

Here is a code :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER  "TRI_MUD_PARAMETER_VW_INS" 
INSTEAD of Insert ON MUD_PARAMETER_VW for each row
DECLARE
  v_id                                         number(10);
  v_borehole_id                                number(10);
begin 
        select SEQ_ID.nextval into v_id from dual;
        select id into v_borehole_id from EPI_BOREHOLE where UBHI=:new.UBHI;

        insert into EPI_FER_MUD_PARAMETERS (ID,LOG_DATE,TOP_DEPTH,BOTTOM_DEPTH,MUD_TYPE,MUD_WT_DENSITY,VISCOSITY,PH,RES_RM,RES_RMF,RES_RMC,FLUID_LOSS, BHT,BHT_UNIT,BHT_DEPTH,SERVICE_COMPANY,HOLE_SIZE,REMARKS,BOREHOLE_ID,INSERT_DATE,INSERT_NAME,UPDATE_DATE,UPDATE_NAME)
        values (v_id,:new.LOG_DATE,:new.TOP_DEPTH,:new.BOTTOM_DEPTH,:new.MUD_TYPE, :new.MUD_WT_DENSITY,:new.VISCOSITY,:new.PH,:new.RES_RM, :new.RES_RMF,:new.RES_RMC,:new.FLUID_LOSS, :new.BHT,:new.BHT_UNIT,:new.BHT_DEPTH,:new.SERVICE_COMPANY,:new.HOLE_SIZE,:new.REMARKS, v_borehole_id,sysdate,USER,sysdate,USER);
    END;

END;
```

Error:--

```
ORA-01403: no data found
ORA-06512: at "FER_EPINET.TRI_MUD_PARAMETER_VW_INS"
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'FER_EPINET.TRI_MUD_PARAMETER_VW_INS'
```

Answer (score 2):

The "no data found" error would suggest that the line that is failing is this:

```
select id into v_borehole_id from EPI_BOREHOLE where UBHI = :new.UBHI;
```

This would occur when no rows meet the condition `UBHI = :new.UBHI`.

There are many ways to fix it.  It is unclear what you might want to do.  Here is one idea:

```
select max(id) into v_borehole_id
from EPI_BOREHOLE
where UBHI = :new.UBHI;
```

That will assign the value of `NULL`.  This will assign the value of `0`:

```
select coalesce(max(id), 0) into v_borehole_id
from EPI_BOREHOLE
where UBHI = :new.UBHI;
```

Comment: thank u sir....bt one thing i want to know ....without using max() ....y the code is throwing error??

Comment: I think he told you.  No data was found by the select.  That raises an exception that isn't handled in your code.

Comment: Aggregate functions such as `min` and `max` return null in this scenario, rather than raising an exception. That can be used (with care, of course) to avoid a load of exception handling code.